# Change a Line of Code based on Configuration selected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config

In my ASP.NET MVC 3 application, I have 2 configurations setup; Play and Live.

Right now, I have to change the following code before loading my application with a configuration based on what I currently have selected:

```
Mailer.SendMessageTo("playEmailAddress", "MailBody");
// Mailer.SendMessageTo("liveEmailAddress", "MailBody");
```

So if I have `Play` configuration selected I'll comment out the `liveEmailAddress` line and vice versa

What I'd like to do is perhaps make use of the `web.config` file to change this code for me without manually doing it every time I load up my application with a different configuration by putting the lines of code in the config file and then reading it from the config file from within my class

Comment: why dont you add these email addresses in the web.config itslef?

Comment: What is the question? How to read settings from web.config? How to store the email address in web config?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Both!

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff do you have only one web.config?

Comment: @prashantht I have 1 web.config which has 2 configs I use the `xdt:Transform` on; `Web.Live.config` and `Web.Play.config`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the "app key" in your web configuration file. Give it anyname like "OptionalEmail" and set the value accordingly.

When you send the email check the value in the configuration file like

> If(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OptionalEmail"]=="PlayEmail")
>   SendEmail using PlayEmail address else SendEmail using Work emai
>   Address.

Hope this help. "ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[use key or index]

Please keep in mind, Config Transformations "xdt" **works only when you deploy your web application**.

Comment: How do I check the value in the configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

it's generally a good idea to have a configuration parameter named "environment" (or the like).
This link explains how to read from the web.config: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610xe886.aspx.

one way to implement this would be:

```
var env = "play";
if( ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["environment"]=="live" ) env="live";
var email = env + "EmailAddress";
Mailer.SendMessageTo(email, "MailBody");
```

as an additional note, if you have multiple developers that each want their own "play"-Address, then you can extend the setting to include the developers machine name:

```
<appSettings>
      <add key="environment" value="play"/>
      <add key="liveEmailAddress" value="a@b.com"/>
      <add key="myCoolPC-playEmailAddress" value="c@d.com"/>
      <add key="otherDevPC-playEmailAddress" value="bubba@test.com"/>
</appSettings>
```

but then you would have to change the implementation above to prefix the hostname before getting the setting, but only if currently in play-mode.